# Dimensional regularization and IR divergences and scale invariance

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, regularization

I want to know if dimensional regularization has any issues if the theory has IR divergences or is scale invariant.

- Does dimensional regularization see "all" kinds of divergences?

  I mean - what does it *exactly* mean when one says that power law divergences and IR divergences disappear in the dimensional regularization. So is more regularization needed in general over and above dimensional regularization?
- Does anything about the divergences get specially constrained if the theory is scale invariant?

  I have often heard it being said that dimensional regularization "preserves" scale invariance.

Comment: so does 'zeta regularization ' :D is an alternative to regularize finit integrals · $\int_{a}^{\infty}x^{m-s} $ for some finite 'a'

Comment: @JoseJavierGarcia Can you kindly expand on your comment? What exactly did you mean?

Comment: i meant that we can also use zeta regularization in renormalization :) , the main drawback of dimensional regularization is that it does not work for dimension-dependent quantities

Comment: @Jose Javier Garcia In what precise sense do you mean "does not work"? Can you give some reference which shows how zeta-regularization helps with the RG flow of non-marginal operators?

Comment: for zeta regualrization the best book is Elizalde's " ZETA REGULARIZATION TECHNIQUES" , or you have my paper for free :) http://www.vixra.org/pdf/1009.0047v4.pdf

Comment: @JoseJavierGarcia Kindly put up your paper on arxiv so that it becomes legitimate to read/cite it!

Comment: i have no academic affiliation so they do not let me put papers in arxiv.org anyway you can check the equations :) to see they are corrects

Comment: García, José Javier http://prespacetime.com/index.php/pst/article/view/498 The Application of Zeta Regularization Method to the Calculation of Certain Divergent Series and Integrals Refined Higgs, CMB from Planck, Departures in Logic, and GR Issues & Solutions vol 4 Nº 3 prespacetime journal http://prespacetime.com/index.php/pst/issue/view/41/showToc

Comment: @JoseJavierGarcia You shall write in LaTeX. Not in Word or yucky variants.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146833/which-renormalisation-techniques-are-available-for-31-qed/443222#443222. As explained in Howard Georgi's notes linked there, dim reg throws away power divergences but not log divergences. You don't want to throw away the log terms though, as they explain how physics changes with scale in renormalisable theories and are used to calculate the beta functions and anomalous dimensions.